# Dropbox selective sync doesn't want to add back a directory

Tags: sync, dropbox

I have recently excluded a directory from sync using selective sync in Dropbox, and now I want to select it again (i.e. return things to normal) and each time I try to tick it back, it says:

```
"The following folder couldn't be added to this computer's Dropbox:"
```

and lists my directory.

Anyone got that and knows how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the command line as described [here](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli#EXCLUDE)

> dropbox exclude remove [DIRECTORY] [DIRECTORY] ...

"remove" removes one or more directories from the exclusion list, then resynchronizes Dropbox.
With no arguments, executes "list".

If you don't have the command line interface [download it here](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py)

Comment: I don't have the command-line version but I do run with the normal Windows Dropbox. If I run this version, won't it create duplications or other problems?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. I could solve it by following steps.

Suppose I want to re-add "Camera Uploads" folder.

1. Go to dropbox folder. Delete "Camera Uploads" folder. See screenshot at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63122560/DropboxFolder.png
2. Go to dropbox preferences (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63122560/DropboxPreferences.png). Tick "Camera Uploads" folder.

Comment: Welcome.  Thanks for trying to help solve this problem.  Your answer is a little confusing, though.  It sounds like you are suggesting to delete the directory you want to add, in which case, there would be nothing to add.  Can you reword your answer to make your solution clearer?

Comment: That edit didn't really help.  What is the minus badge?  The "file system" is the confusing part.  That usually refers to what is stored on the hard disk in the system's directory structure.  Are you referring to a view in Dropbox?  Would this essentially be a duplicate of the TomEus answer?